# vue js is not a function

Tags: laravel, vue.js

this is my error code "this.fetchArticle is not a function"

```
created(){
        this.fetchArticles();
    },
    method: {
        fetchArticles(){
            fetch('api/articles')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data)
            })
        }
    }
```

thank you

Comment: i am vue beginner

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Hi, Being a beginner does not mean you don't explain your question properly :) Not many will understand your question. Read here before posting https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its methods not method

```
created(){
        this.fetchArticles();
    },
    methods: {
        fetchArticles(){
            fetch('api/articles')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data)
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: No worries! Glad to be able to help.